# Nginx with SPDY Draft 3, is possible?

Tags: nginx, protocol, spdy

I'm currently using Nginx 1.4.1 with SPDY module.

Unfortunately, the Nginx SPDY module, work only with the Draft 2 of protocol.

Is there a way to use Nginx, with SPDY Draft 3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nginx now supports Spdy Draft 3.1 from 1.5.10 version.

Answer (score 7):

From the research I've done, there is no current module for SPDY Draft 3. It appears development has basically stalled. You're out of luck unless you code your own module unfortunately.

Comment: I also researched in Google, and I found no (also experimental) module for SPDY 3. I hoped someone was more lucky. Therefore, the only SPDY3 webserver is Jetty actually?

Comment: Apache supports it too.

Comment: Ah, unfurnately apache is less performance than nginx... I hope the improve as soon as possible the support...

Answer (score 3):

You may want to read explanation on why spdy/2 is OK (and even better) for now: https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/4407760#1084091

Comment: Note to current visitors: Chrome and Firefox (at least) have since dropped SPDY/2 support completely.

Answer (score 1):

Spdy/3 is now available for NGINX. Please see the following link for installation instructions:

http://mailman.nginx.org/pipermail/nginx-devel/2014-January/004890.html

```
This patch upgrades implementation of SPDY protocol in the 
ngx_http_spdy_module from draft 2 to draft 3.1.

How-to for newbies:

 1) Make sure that you have OpenSSL 1.0.1 or later.

 2) Download nginx/1.5.9:

 % wget http://nginx.org/download/nginx-1.5.9.tar.gz

 3) Unpack it:

 % tar xvfz nginx-1.5.9.tar.gz
 % cd nginx-1.5.9

 4) Download and apply the patch:

 % wget http://nginx.org/patches/patch.spdy-v31.txt
 % patch -p1 < patch.spdy-v31.txt

 5) Configure and build nginx:

 % ./configure --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_spdy_module
 % make

 Hint: have a look at http://nginx.org/en/docs/configure.html
 and try "./configure --help" for more useful options.
```

Comment: And that patch was released today as part of nginx 1.5.10.